# Key Error is generated by Pivot_table for column which is not used in Pivot Table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am creating Pivot table from my dataframe which contains mix of columns such as Text, Numbers, Date and Time.
I am able to successfully read the file into dataframe and able to process few groupby operations. Based on this I am trying to create the Pivot Table which group the data by week and count certain occurrence of data based on some criteria.  However the Pivot_table is keep raising Keyerror for column which is not used in Pivot Table.

Here is my Dataframe:

```
H1      H2        H3            H4      H5    H6    H7    H8    H10
RA2   RB2, H2    2020-07-25    11:30   60    1774   RG2   RH2   RJ2
RA3   RB3, H2    2020-07-25    11:30   60    1791   RG3   RH3   RJ3
RA4   RB4, H2    2020-07-25    11:30   35    1806   RG4   RH4   RJ4
RA5   RB1, H3    2020-07-25    12:30   35    1771   RG5   RH5   RJ5
RA6   RB2, H3    2020-07-25    12:45   60    1813   RG6   RH6   RJ6
RA7   RB3, H3    2020-07-25    13:00   60    1789   RG7   RH7   RJ7
RA8   RB4, H3    2020-07-25    13:00   60    1790   RG8   RH8   RJ8
RA9   RB1, H4    2020-07-25    13:00   60    1808   RG9   RH9   RJ9
RA10  RB2, H4    2020-07-25    14:00   60    1822   RG10  RH10  RJ10
```

Here is my code where its failing:

```
            pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['H1', pd.Grouper(key='H3', freq='W-MON')], columns='H10',\
            margins=True, aggfunc={'H10':np.count_nonzero}).reset_index()
```

Error I am getting is as follow:

```
Function: createPivot Raised:  'H2'
```

I am stuck with this issue for a week now and unable to get around it.  I have also posted another post related to this issue on SO but unable to get any answer.

So I really appreciate if I can get some expert opinion.

Really appreciate your help and consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the pivot table is, as it doesn't have the expected output, but if you want to simply aggregate it, you can do it with `df.groupby('H3')['H10'].transform(np.count_nonzero)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table will try to use all columns as `values` in your dataframe, unless you set them explicitly. So seeing a dictionary in the `aggfunc` argument it tries to look up the aggregating function for each remaining column, not just for H10.

However, in your example, even if you specify H10 as `values` explicitly, you'll run into the issue of trying to use the same column for both `columns` and `values` arguments which gives the `Grouper for 'H10' not 1-dimensional` error.

You might be better off with `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(
    index=[df['H1'],  df['H3']],
    values=df['H10'], columns=df['H10'],
    margins=True,  aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)

H10              RJ10  RJ2  RJ3  RJ4  RJ5  RJ6  RJ7  RJ8  RJ9  All
H1   H3                                                           
RA10 2020-07-25   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA2  2020-07-25   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA3  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA4  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA5  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA6  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
RA7  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN    1
RA8  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN    1
RA9  2020-07-25   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0    1
All  NaT          1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0    9
```